# rails migration generating random tables. Where is this coming from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-migration

When I run `rails db:migrate` without a new migration it seems to have added two new tables: `questions` and `questions_1`.

In my schema file I see:

```
  create_table "questions", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "id"
    t.text "text"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "organization_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.bigint "account_id"
    t.bigint "team_id"
  end

  create_table "questions_1", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "id"
    t.text "text"
    t.boolean "active"
    t.integer "organization_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.bigint "account_id"
    t.bigint "team_id"
  end
```

I don't have any migrations making these tables. I'm guessing this is some sort of convention. Where do I look to fix this? All recent changes are in the `app/` directory and a migration I made has been rolled back and then deleted. Yet when I run `rails db:migrate` I always get these new tables.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails won't create tables with any name other than the ones specified in a migration. If the table already exists then it will throw an error.

I believe someone has run a migration creating the second table on your database, and then deleted the migration. When rails creates your schema.rb file, it uses your database rather than any migrations, meaning this file reflects your actual database state rather than the one your migrations suggest would be the case.

If you're sure you don't want the second table and it has no data in it, then you can write out a new migration to delete this table, run it, and then delete it. This will return your database state to the one your migrations suggest would be the case. You can then run `rake db:schema:dump` to update your schema.

Comment: thank you. the answer was that i imported a dump and there were referential constrain errors. Running `db:migrate` then moved those changes from my broken db into my schema file. The trick was to fix the dump import. thank you

Comment: Happy to help if I did :D